# SQLiteException: no such table: trainingsplan (code 1) while compiling: select statment

Tags: java, database, sqlite

**So this ist my code for the Database**

```
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
private SQLiteStatement insertStatement;



private String DB_Table = "trainingsplan";


private String INSERT = "insert into " + DB_Table
        + "(zweckkuerzel,aktuellertp,zweck)" + "values (?,?,?)";
```

**It says the error is in the select statment.**

```
private String SEL_ROW = "select zweckkuerzel,aktuellertp,zweck from "
        + DB_Table;

private String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + DB_Table
        + "(zweckkuerzel String, " 
        + "aktuellertp String NOT NULL, "
        + "zweck String)";

private String CREATE_INDEX = "create index if not exists " + DB_Table
        + "_ind " + "ON " + DB_Table + " (zweckkuerzel)";
```

Here i create my Dao and Tabel

```
    TrainingsplanDao trainingsDao= new TrainingsplanDao(db);
    trainingsDao.createTable();
    trainingsDao.fillTable();
```

This is the Construcotr of my Dao

```
public TrainingsplanDao(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    this.db = db;
    try {
        insertStatement = db.compileStatement(INSERT);
        Log.d("ANDRO VEGI", "Create INSERT product");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.d("ANDRO VEGI", "NO Database, NO INSERT  TrainingsplanDao()");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running your queries in order? Perhaps you're selecting before you've created the table. Post more code.

Comment: in my OpenHelper I first create the Table
I have edited the previos code

Comment: If you're recently touched the table schema, uninstall the app so the older version of your database file is removed.

Comment: Thanks it worked!
But i still get the error no sucht table but everything works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly says there is no table named `trainingsplan` is found in db. Please ensure that it actually exists in the same name.

Comment: how can I see this, if the table really exists?

Comment: Use SQLite database browser to view the database